# ¿Como solucionar un error con post?

Tags: laravel

Buenas quiero editar un usuario, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD.

En que puedo estar cometiendo el error, estoy usando el update de mi controller y en mi vista especifico el método patch.

Este es mi controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class usuarioscrud extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $datos['usuarios'] = User::paginate(10);

        return view('usuarios.index', $datos);
    }

       public function create()
    {
        return view('usuarios.crear');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //$datosusuario= request()->all();
        $datosusuario= request()->except('_token', 'Agregar');

        $registro = new User();
        $registro->name= $datosusuario['name'];
        $registro->email= $datosusuario['email'];
        $registro->password= bcrypt($datosusuario['password']);
        $registro->name= $datosusuario['name'];
        $registro->codpermiso= $datosusuario['codpermiso'];
        $registro->save();
        return back()->with('mensaje', 'Usuario registrado!');
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        User::destroy($id);
        return redirect('/usuarios');
    }
     public function edit($id)
    {
        $usuario= User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('usuarios.edit', compact('usuario'));
    }
       public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $datousuario= request()->all();
        $registro= User::where('id','=',$id);
        $registro->name= $datosusuario['name'];
        $registro->email= $datosusuario['email'];
        $registro->password= bcrypt($datosusuario['password']);
        $registro->name= $datosusuario['name'];
        $registro->codpermiso= $datosusuario['codpermiso'];
        $registro->save();
        return redirect('/usuarios');
    }
}
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
<form action="{{url('/usuarios/'.$usuario->id)}}" method="POST">
 @csrf
 @method('PATCH')
    <label for="name">{{'Nombre:'}}</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{$usuario->name}}">
</br>
    <label for="email">{{'Email:'}}</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="{{$usuario->email}}">
</br>
    <label for="password">{{'Contraseña:'}}</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="{{$usuario->password}}">
</br>
<label for="codpermiso">{{'Nivel de usuario:'}}</label>
    <select name="codpermiso" id="codpermiso" class="form-control">
        <option>{{$usuario->codpermiso}}</option>
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
        <option >3</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    Recuerde que 1.- Es Invitado, 2.- Usuario y 3.-Administrador
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="Editar">
</br>
</form>
```

y este es mi web.php

```
Route::Resource('usuarios','usuarioscrud');
```

[image: Ruta]

Tambien tengo una vista create podría estar habiendo conflicto con esta? La paso tambien aqui:

```
<form action="{{url('/usuarios')}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <label for="name">{{'Nombre:'}}</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
</br>
    <label for="email">{{'Email:'}}</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="">
</br>
    <label for="password">{{'Contraseña:'}}</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
</br>
<label for="codpermiso">{{'Nivel de usuario:'}}</label>
    <select name="codpermiso" id="codpermiso" class="form-control">
        <option >1</option>
        <option >2</option>
        <option >3</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    Recuerde que 1.- Es Invitado, 2.- Usuario y 3.-Administrador
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="Agregar">
</br>
</form>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, porque no entiendo muy bien a que se puede deber el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar invocando de esta forma;

```
..
<form action="{{route('usuarios.update',$usuario)}}" method="POST">
 @csrf
 @method('PATCH')
..
```

Y para el caso de CREATE, según tus rutas, es un GET, y vos lo declarás como POST

```
<form action="{{url('/usuarios')}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Si es que el post se encuentra en el metodo STORE, gracias por tu ayuda me funciona perfectamente.